# Python in Filemaker Pro

Tags: python, filemaker

I was hoping to calculate fields using some rather complicated functions, which I don't think I can realistically write in filemaker.

I would prefer to write a script to extract data into python, perform some procedures and then import it back into filemaker (so a user can see the results "live" in layouts, without having to leave filemaker).

Is this possible in Filemaker Pro?

Comment: Can I use something like this: http://code.google.com/p/pyfilemaker/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That python module is meant to work with FileMaker server: send GET/POST requests, get back response in XML, and parse it. Technically you can use it to do a lot (add and delete records, run scripts, etc.) but in your case it won't fit.

There are some plug-ins that can execute shell commands, so this way you can call Python from a command line. Other than that you cannot do this.

But in some time (a few months) there will be a FileMaker plug-in with embedded Python :)

Comment: Thanks very much for that, embedded python would be so useful! Will this work in Filemaker Pro as well as Filemaker Server?

Comment: This is the idea. It will work in Pro and in Server. The difference is that while `pyfilemaker` works from outside merely as a web client, the plug-in would work from inside with full access to the plug-in API. It's not that that API can do everything in FM, but quite a lot.

Comment: oooooh, that's brilliant news! How exciting! Where can we keep up to date with the progress of this plug-in?

Comment: Good question :) There's no official site yet, but I'll be posting updates [to this blog](http://mikhail-edoshin.blogspot.com/).

Comment: How's this coming along? :)

Comment: @AndyHayden I have a beta version for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I have a FileMaker plug-in called bBox that executes Python code. Mac OS X only, but a free download at http://beezwax.net/bbox.

It has these Python related functions:

- bBox_PythonCompile ( mode; script )
- bBox_PythonExecute ( mode )
- bBox_PythonFinalize
- bBox_PythonGetVar ( name {; asType) }
- bBox_PythonSetVar ( name; value {; asType} )

A few parts are admittedly still a bit rough. The types that the GetVar and SetVar functions can work with are limited, for example. But the code has been out for a while with only a few reported issues, all since fixed.

I've worked with a couple solutions that used pyFilemaker with good results. It isn't getting much attention these days. On the other hand, there haven't been many external changes to FileMaker's XML interface either.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout PyFileMaker (python object wrapper for FM.) It enables you to access/edit FileMaker server database.